# C++ overloaded output operator

Tags: c++, overloading, output

so I am coding my c++ homework assignment and there is a final part where he wants us to Replace the formatted output method (toString) with an overloaded output/insertion operator. TO be 100% honest I have no idea what he means by this. I've searched around a bit and found example codes using an overloaded insertion operator, but can't seem to find how to incorporate  it into my code. Though I think I may be looking in the wrong place. My toString is as follows:

```
string Movie::toString() const {
    ostringstream oS;
    oS << "\n\n====================== Movie Information\n"
    << "\n             Movie Title:\t" << title << "  (" << releaseYear << ")"
    << "\n    US Rank & Box Office:\t" << usRank << "\t$" << usBoxOffice
    << "\nNon-US Rank & Box Office:\t" << nonUSRank << "\t$" << nonUSBoxOffice
    << "\n World Rank & Box Office:\t" << worldRank << "\t$" << worldBoxOffice
    << "\n";
    return oS.str();
}
```

Like I mentioned I'm not sure what "overloaded" means, so If for some reason this isn't enough information for  you to help me with the problem directly, then can you give me a brief description of what he may mean by replacing the current output with an overloaded output operator. Thank You

edit: This is the next question I have. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924621/c-overloaded-output-operator-cont

Comment: This quesion posted a few minutes ago has an example of what you're refering to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924007/overloading-with-duplicate-symbol-linking-error

Comment: Have you tried to look up "overload" in Wikipedia?

Comment: I did actually. I was hoping for a secondary explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To overload a function means to provide other functions with the same name but different parameter types. Operators can also be overloaded. Many operators have a corresponding function that can be overloaded called `operator??`, where `??` is the operator itself. For example if you have two objects `x` and `y` of class type `T`, you could overload `operator+`. Overloading an operator allows you to give some meaning to using that operator with the type. So now you could do `x + y`.

The stream insertion operator is `<<`. It's what you use when you do `std::cin << "hello";` - it *inserts* into the stream. This operator can also be overloaded, just as `+` was overloaded above. The function you need to overload is called `operator<<`.

There are two ways to overload a binary operator like `<<` (binary because it takes two operands, one on the left side and one on the right, `left << right`). One is to make it a member of the type of `left` and give it a single parameter of the type of `right`. The other is to make it a non-member function with two parameters, one the type of `left` and the other the type of `right`. Since the type of your `left` will be `std::ostream`, you can't modify the class (because it's provided by the standard), so you'll have to go with option two.

So your free function needs to look something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Movie& movie) {
  // Insert everything you want into `os`
  return os;
}
```

Now this function will be called whenever you do `<<` with an `std::ostream` on the left and a `Movie` on the right.

Comment: I understand how the operator is overloaded now, and ways it can be used, but still not completely sure why you use it. Thank you for the answer. I will study on this more.

Comment: Though I do have another question if your up for it. I also have a getMovie function where it picks out a movie using and index. Would I overload the function the same way we did with tostring.

Comment: @JasonSchayer You use it because you want to be able to do `Movie m; std::cout << m;`. This will print out the contents of the movie `m` in the form you specify. Just like doing `std::cout << 10;` will print out the `int` 10. Now you can print out a `Movie`!

Comment: @JasonSchayer If your new question is for clarification, ask it here, sure. If it's separate, post a new question on SO.

Comment: Ill post it in another SO just to make things easier and link it here

Answer (score 3):

I think your task is meant to be writing an overloaded `operator <<` which allows you to write the string representation of your object to an output stream:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Movie& movie) {
    os << "\n\n====================== Movie Information\n"
       << "\n             Movie Title:\t" << movie.title << "  (" << movie.releaseYear << ")"
       << "\n    US Rank & Box Office:\t" << movie.usRank << "\t$" << movie.usBoxOffice
       << "\nNon-US Rank & Box Office:\t" << movie.nonUSRank << "\t$" << movie.nonUSBoxOffice
       << "\n World Rank & Box Office:\t" << movie.worldRank << "\t$" << movie.worldBoxOffice
       << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

And you use this operator as you could do with built-in types:

```
Movie m;

// Do something with m

cout << m;      // Write m to the standard output
```

Comment: Thank you, both you and sftrabbit helped alot